# Limits - $\sqrt{(xa)^2 +ax + 1} - \sqrt{(ax)^2 + 1}$

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x \to\infty}\sqrt{(xa)^2  +ax + 1} - \sqrt{(ax)^2 + 1}$$

I came across this question and am not able to get a specific result...
Please Help ME!!

Comment: Please include your thoughts and efforts (work in progress) in this and future posts. 
You are more likely to receive positive/constructive feedback that way.  
Formatting your post helps too.
Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

As usual:
$$\sqrt a-\sqrt b=(\sqrt a-\sqrt b)\frac{\sqrt a+\sqrt b}{\sqrt a+\sqrt b}.$$

Comment: Thanks just ended up applying l'hopital in a wrong way...
Everything is fine now... Thanks to you..

Comment: Followin Surb's answer: You should get the limit: $\frac{1}{2} $ for $ a \neq 0$